# jQuery DataTables Toggle selected rows with a button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I'm trying to toggle only selected rows within a table using a button but, so far, all I've got is to filter only those in the current page within a collection of pages. Could you please help me what to do?

```
{
  text: '<i class="fa fa-list" style="color:orange;"></i>',
  action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
      //This works only in current page
      $('#tblUsers tbody tr').not('.selected').toggle();
      //This doesn't work at all
      tableUsers.rows({ selected: true }).data().draw();
  },
  className: 'vcaBtnTable'
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... after hours of try and error, I've came with this solution that works ebautifully to my purposes.

```
if (tableActions.rows({ selected: false }).count() == 0) {
                        dt.ajax.reload(function () {
                            dt.rows('.selected').select();
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#tblActions").DataTable().rows({ selected: false }).remove().draw();
                    }
```

Bear in mind that I had initialized my table as follows:

```
tableActions = $('#tblActions').DataTable({....});
```